# How to make an equivalent apply() function of R for Pyspark?

Tags: r, pyspark

I am quite new to pyspark programming.
I want to make a similar function to `apply()` in R to calculate covariance of my spark datframe (with over 1000 columns) and return it as a vector.
Also if there is an alternative to function in the pyspark, I would be grateful to community to guide me through.

Thanks

Comment: You Should use transform function.
Read more about it here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called `map` in Python: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-map-transformation/

Comment: the apply() returns the vectorized output of the dataframe or an input matrix, the map function does the otherwise, it gives the  RDD as an output.

Comment: Why apply do you want to have in pyspark? `sapply`? `lapply` `rapply`?

Comment: just apply(), actually I am trying to replicate this line in pyspark `cv <- apply(log2cpm, 1, compute_cv)` where `compute_cv` is a user defined function for computing the covariance. The `cv` variable gets assigned by a vector. `log2cpm` is the normalized matrix

Comment: Looks like applying a function to each row of a table. Look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-loop-through-each-row-of-dataframe-in-pyspark/